# Does Microsoft Teams meeting Apps works for live events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to create an App for Microsoft Teams live events.

I've found that it is possible to Teams Meetings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-apps-in-meetings

The documentation doesn't mention Live Events.

Is it possible?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no API to set up live event in teams. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-live-events/set-up-for-teams-live-events). The closest one i can remember is that you can use MeetNow, but it is done in Graph API using application permissions. So a bot, application or a Flow / Logic Apps can create a Teams meeting.

Comment: The problem is not to setup a Live event using the API. I need to run a custom Teams app in the Live Event interface. The link that I've referenced shows that it is possible on Teams Meetings interface

Comment: @MuriloMacielCurti This feature is currently not there for Live Events Interface. If you want Teams to come up with this feature in future,  Please raise a [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform) here.